# Bind jquery UI date-picker on focus of input element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi i have a situation like i need to bind the jquery UI datepicker({}) function when the input element is focused.i am not able to achieve it with the below code ,so guys plz help how can i bind the datepicker function when the input element is focused

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <title> Jquery UI Date Picker </title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <input type="text" id="date" />

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       //$('#date').datepicker({});
       $('#date').on('foucs',function(){
          $(this).datepicker({});
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In fact you don't need to datepicker when focus,just set input readonly,like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ananis/sdq26rhs/

Comment: I have to bind the functionality on focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open datepicker using onclick event:

```
<input type="text" id="date" onclick="$('#date').datepicker();$('#date').datepicker('show');" />
```

OR

```
$( "#date" ).focus(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker();
    $('#date').datepicker('show');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.i don't have access to the input element ,i have to do everything in jquery only.is there a way i can achieve it

Comment: ,these input elements are generated dynamically so there wont be any id or class assigned to it,for example purpose i have just added it.there is a callback function triggered on the input focus element,so i have only chance of using $(this) inside the callback function

Comment: Thanks Dhara but why on the first time focus it is not working.it is only working on the second time focus only

Comment: is it first time going into .focus event? try by alerting

Comment: alert and console.log() works on the first focus itself ,i don't know why this date-picker is not working on first focus .can you plz try on your end

Comment: You should initialize the datepicker when the elements are created.  If you don't have id and they are dynamically created you should make that clear in your question.  In that case just make sure you initialize the datepicker on new elements as they are created, not when they are focused.

Comment: @codegeek initialize date-picker outside focus - and in focus just show the date-picker...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

code should be:

```
$( "#date" ).focus(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
});
```

ref for focus: https://api.jquery.com/focus/
ref for date picker: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/